# get informaion about the user from its http request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httprequest

Q:

I want to ask about how to get the **Computer name** and the **account name** of the user who making an `http request` to my web site.according to his request.

When i search i find that:

- `REMOTE_HOST`

  The name of the host that is making
  the request. If the server does not
  have this information, it will set
  REMOTE_ADDR and leave this empty.

  **Why** the server may never contain the host name? and how can i fix
  this?
- I use `REMOTE_USER` , `LOGON_USER` ,
  `AUTH_USER` to get the account name
  but it doesn't contain any data also

.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Request.ServerVariables object like

```
// will return the host name making the request

    string s = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] 


    // will return the computer name
    string s = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]
```

**EDIT**

If you want to get computer name then try following

```
string computer_name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName;

    Response.Write(computer_name);
```

**EDIT II**

//Retrieving Client Machine details

```
System.Net.IPAddress[] strClientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName);
string strClientMachineName = Environment.MachineName.ToString().Trim();
string strClientUserName = Environment.UserName.ToString().Trim();
string strClientDomainName = Environment.UserDomainName.ToString().Trim();
string strClientOSVersion = Environment.OSVersion.ToString().Trim();
```

For more server variables check out the following link

[IIS Server Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks but,The first one give me `127.0.0.1` ,, the second one give me `localhost` ,while my Computer name is: `mm_h`.

Comment: is this because i try those methods locally or not?

Comment: hmmm `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` give the name of the server.
`Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]` give me the ip address.not the host name, i wanna to get the host name and the windows account according to the request.thanks

Comment: the method works perfectly locally, but when published and i try to run , it gets `172` the first part of my `ip address`.

Comment: when run locally i get `mm_h`.
|

Comment: when running from server i get `172`.

Comment: according to your update ::
i get the whole ip address, not the host name.

Comment: hmmm,,sorry

i get right data but for server ,the hostname for the server, the user name for the server not the data of the client who make the request.

Comment: @just_name: It's strange ...give me some time ...I am looking for some other solution

Comment: @Just_name:Sorry I can't find any solution ....every body is suggesting the code (I have suggested to u) with some medication :(

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: both of them get the ip address not the `hostname`.